# Facebook share button doesn't work gives an 401 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, vue.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add a Facebook share button for my GitHub account. But when I press the share button I am getting this error.

[image]

**This is my very simple code.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script
      async
      defer
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v10.0&appId=236920251173345&autoLogAppEvents=1"
      nonce="rMldTG7p"
    ></script>
    <div
      class="fb-share-button"
      data-href="https://github.com/pathum-kalhan"
      data-layout="button"
      data-size="large"
    >
      <a
        target="_blank"
        href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fqa.gudppl.com%2Fopportunities%2F2420b311-b7d1-4c5c-a772-068ae10cb748&amp;src=sdkpreparse"
        class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"
        >Share</a
      >
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I search google also, some say this is happening due to localhost and this works fine at HTTPS level.
But I deploy this to a sever as well https://yukon-a2140.web.app/ but the results are the same.
This code is generated from the Facebook developers console. I am wondering why this isn't working?

Do I need to specifically add my GitHub domain to the Facebook app account or something else?

Any help!

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: I put the URL through the Facebook debug tool to refresh the cache, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpathum-kalhan - check again, if things have changed now.

Comment: Thanks. Put this as an answer. I will mark it as the answer. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Facebook had an old result cached.

Putting the URL through the Facebook sharing debug tool and triggering a re-scrape to refresh the cache fixed the issue.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpathum-kalhan

Comment: Thanks a lot. =)